# When writing a differential equation, when do you take $+\text{d}x$ and when do you take $-\text{d}x$?

Tags: forces, work, vectors, spring, conventions

When writing a differential equation I'm confused as to when to write $+\text{d}x$ a and when to write $-\text{d}x$ a where $x$ represents some quantity.

For example, I wanted to derive the equation for work done by a spring.
I tried it on two cases, one when spring is extended from natural length and is getting compressed and the other when the spring is compressed from natural length. I did as follows:

1. $$\text{d}W = kx (-\text{d}x)\cos{0} $$
   Now integrating this equation from say $x_1$ to $x_2$ we
   get the work done by spring. That's alright, but now,
2. When the spring is getting compressed from natural 
   length: 
   $$\text{d}W = kx(-\text{d}x) \cos{\pi}$$ 
   Now integrating from say lower limit $x=0$ to upper limit $x= x_2$ (in the case when the spring is still compressed at $x = x_2$), we get the work done to be positive whereas it should be negative.

Now my question is how to write the differential equations, mainly concerned with the plus and minus signs to be assigned.

Answer (score 2):

The $dx$ is actually a vector $d\vec{x}$ (because $\vec{x}$ is actually a vector). A vector's sign depends on your coordinate axes, e.g. if you pick right to be positive then left pointing vectors are negative.

In general, the work done $W$ is given by
$$
W = \int \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{x} = \int Fdx \cos(\theta)
$$
where $\theta$ is the angle between $\vec{F}$ and $d\vec{x}$.

**Work done on the spring:**
[image]

In both cases $\vec{F}$ and $d\vec{x}$ point in the same direction, so the angle between them $\theta = 0$. Therefore $\cos(\theta) = \cos(0) = 1$, and work is positive. Alternatively you can decompose $\vec{F}$ and $d\vec{x}$ into their components, which for compression looks like:
$$
\vec{F} = F (-\hat x) + 0 \hat y \quad \text{and} \quad  
d\vec{x} = dx (-\hat x) + 0 \hat y
$$
And then perform the dot product
$$
\vec{F} \cdot d\vec{x} = Fdx \ (-\hat x) \cdot (-\hat x) = Fdx \ \hat x \cdot  \hat x = Fdx
$$
If the spring obeys Hooke's law, then you can plug in $F = kx$ and integrate to $W = \frac{1}{2} kx^2$.

**Work done by the spring:**
[image]

Now the angle between $\vec{F}$ and $d\vec{x}$ is $\theta = 180 ^\circ$, so $\cos(\theta) = -1$ and work is negative. Again with component decomposition for the compression scenario
$$
\vec{F} = F (\hat x) + 0 \hat y \quad \text{and} \quad  
d\vec{x} = dx (-\hat x) + 0 \hat y
$$
and perform the dot product
$$
\vec{F} \cdot d\vec{x} = Fdx \ (-\hat x) \cdot (\hat x) = -Fdx \ \hat x \cdot  \hat x = -Fdx
$$
So the work done by the spring $W = -\frac{1}{2}kx^2$.

Answer (score 0):

You might get a wrong sign due to $cos(0)= 1$ and $cos(\pi)= -1$. You either take $x$ as a cartesian coordinate and integrate over it or you use polar coordinates with some maximum elongation $x$ which is constant. In your question you are mixing up both.

The conventional sign here is $-$, however it depends on your way of counting the work, ie work done to or by the system.

Answer (score 0):

basic concept is to set up a coordinate system , Cartesian would be good here

Here, 
I'm calculating work done **BY** the spring

origin is the point where spring is in natural position (for us to use F = -Kx , otherwise, it would also contain some constant too, ex- if our spring's natural length is at (2,5) and spring only moves in along x axis direction, then 
F = - K (x-2) )

If, you move in the assigned positive x direction, change is +ve and dx is +ve , when we move in opposite direction it's negative
but that should not be a problem in any case, dx is a signed variable not something that can only hold +ve values, (In integration, if we reverse limits, result changes sign, hence, we already have a dot product in integration function itself) so, simple integration of F.dx from x1 to x2 will give the answer, where all distances must be from the origin with sign

We could also, calculate work by taking everything positive and performing proper vector dot product, but in complex problems , you will be left scratching your head and there is a reason why coordinate systems are in every imaginable field

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the direction you assign while using $dx$. It is generally a vector, so the sign will automatically be adjusted according the operation used and its direction relative to other operand vectors.

In your case, you are calculating the work done **by the spring**. The force due to a spring is always directed to its mean position. With this in mind, now consider the cases you have taken (note that $dx$ vector is taken along the direction of elongation or compression in the spring):

Case 1: elongation. the displacement vector is directed away from the mean position. So the work done is $kx.dxcos\pi$. If you integrate this from $x_1$ to $x_2$ (the **magnitude** of initial and final elongation respectively.), you get work done by the spring as $-(\frac{1}{2}kx_2^2-\frac{1}{2}kx_1^2)$.

Case 2: the direction of vectors are interchanged, so the angle between them is again $\pi$ When you integrate, keep in mind that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are the **magnitudes** of initial and final compression respectively, so they are always positive quantities. The final result will be the same as in Case 1.

Note: If you were calculating the work done by the force deforming the spring, the answer would have been positive.